# How can I use Pandas to add a combination of dataframe loops that are not listed in python

Tags: python, pandas

```
a = [["a1","b1"],["a2","b2"],["a3","b3"],["a4","b4"],["a5","b5"]]

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ["a1","a2","a3","a4"], 'B' : ["b1","b2","b3", "b4"] , 'mean' : ["13.4","12,1","10.0","11.5"]})
```

How do I add a combination that is not in the list "a" to the data frame row?

I want to use `contains()` or `isin()`

expected result 
The list that does not exist populates the average of the values with the default 0.

```
pd.DataFrame({'A' : ["a1","a2","a3","a4","a5"], B' : ["b1","b2","b3", "b4","b5"] ,'mean' : ["13.4","12,1","10.0","11.5", "0"]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `DataFrame` constructor and [`DataFrame.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) to original, then remove duplicates by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) by specify columns and last replace missing values by `fillna`:

```
a = [["a1","b1"],["a2","b2"],["a3","b3"],["a4","b4"],["a5","b5"]]

df1 = df.append(pd.DataFrame(a,columns=['A','B'])).drop_duplicates(subset=['A','B']).fillna(0)

print (df1)
    A   B  mean
0  a1  b1  13.4
1  a2  b2  12,1
2  a3  b3  10.0
3  a4  b4  11.5
4  a5  b5     0
```

Another idea with `merge`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['A','B']).merge(df, how='left').fillna(0)
```